# HTML5 Audio Element Stops Playing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I would like use an HTML5 audio element such that it has multiple "channels." Normally, with a simple audio tag, if I press the play button once, it will play; however, if I press play again while the audio is still playing, it won't play the again. Essentially, I want the same sound to be able to be played again simultaneously unless all of the channels are playing.

To do this, I'm loading many audio tags. Here is my code to load the audio files:

```
function loadAllAudios(number) {
    toLoad = number;
    loaded = 0;
    audios = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
        // Random test audio file here
        loadAudio("http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse."); // Leave off extension
    }
}
```

And the `loadAudio` function is as follows:

```
function loadAudio(source) {
    var aud = document.createElement("audio");
    aud.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
        ++loaded;
    });
    aud.src = source + (aud.canPlayType("ogg") ? "ogg" : "mp3");
    audios.push(aud);
};
```

To keep track of which audio element is playing, I have an array called `audios`. The elements at the beginning of the array have probably ended, while those at the end are probably still playing. When an audio element starts playing, it is moved from the beginning to the end.
This is the code that gets executed when you press play:

```
console.log(audios);
// Make sure everything is loaded, and that audios isn't an empty array
if (loaded === toLoad && audios && audios.length) {
    var curAudio = audios[0];
    curAudio.play();
    // Move the first element to the end of the array
    // so that we don't play it again while it is still playing
    audios.push(audios.shift());
}
```

The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/XgRH4/1/

My problem is that, for example, if I load three channels, after clicking play 4 times, the code stops working, even if all the audios have ended. I thought it might have been that the element isn't moved to the end correctly, but a `console.log` shows that all the audio elements are still there.

**Edit**: Of the browsers I tested in (Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer 11), the code works only in Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: You approach seems quite primitive … I suggest that you look into what properties, methods and events the audio element provides, so that you can f.e. properly handle/check whether it has finished playing. Starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: There is nothing to help play the same audio element simultaneously. I would use WebAudio, but it doesn't have a lot of support across browsers.

Comment: _“There is nothing to help play the same audio element simultaneously”_ – of course not, because that is impossible. This is just to rare a use case that they would have build anything like that into the spec. You will still need multiple audio elements for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canplaythrough` event will fire more than once for single file, causing unexpected `++loaded` (even when the file was already loaded) and thus `loaded === toLoad` condition will return `false`.

Comment: That seems to work - I removed the event listener so that it wouldn't fire twice. But I thought canplaythrough would fire "when the user agent can play the media, and estimates that enough data has been loaded to play the media up to its end without having to stop for further buffering of content." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/canplaythrough) Is this a bug?

Comment: `canplaythrough` event fires when `readyState` attribute is changed to `HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA`. When `play()` method is called 2nd time, `readyState` is changed to `HAVE_METADATA` and then to `HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA`, causing `canplaythrough` event to fire again.